# Powershell run batch files in background, continue executing and later wait for batch files to finish

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, background-process

I have a powershell script which sets up a dev environment. During this proccess it calls a coupld of batch files.

I would like the powershell script to continue processing until it reaches a point in the script where it needs the batch files to have finished.

Simple test batch file **"md.cmd"**

```
@echo Create directory
md testDirectory
```

**PowerShell script**

```
$job1 = Start-Job {d:\test\md.cmd}

# run some scripts

while($job1.state -eq "Running")
{
    # wait for batch files to end
}

# run some more script using what the batch file did
```

The problem with this is that I cannot get the batch file to execute using `Start-Job`.

How can I execute a batch file as a background process or even in a new command window, keep focus in the powershell script window and know when the batch file has finished.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as long as you check the job state correctly:

```
$job1 = Start-Job {cmd /c d:\test\md.cmd}
#run some scripts
while($job1.state -eq "Running")
{
    #wait for batch files to end
}
#run some more script using what the batch file did
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. I have tried adding cmd to the scriptblock before just not with the /c argument.

Comment: Define `doesn't work`? What happens when you type `Receive-Job` to get the output? Are you sure you're not running into a path variable problem and the directory you're expecting to see isn't getting created elsewhere?

Comment: And you mentioned the `cmd` addition - did you note the use of `$job1.state` here? That's going to be the key. And also your current test `cmd` file needs to at least have a sleep or something otherwise it'll have finished by the time you get to checking the job state

Comment: Even though the ps script is on my desktop and I set-location to d:\test the directory is being created in c:\windows\system32.

Comment: That's because that's where the home of `cmd` is. You need to do a `cd` in your batch script too

Answer (score 1):

start-job only exists in Powershell versions later than 3.0, so make sure you have the correct version installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Start-Sleep` between `Start-Job` and `while loop` to avoid this bug because in the case of your code, it takes a split second to update the status of the job by when the while loop would've already run. This causes the `$job1.state` to still show "Idle" so this would never enter the while loop.

```
$job1 = Start-Job {cmd /c d:\test\md.cmd}

Start-Sleep 5 # to give time to update job status

# run some scripts
while($job1.state -eq "Running")
{
    # wait for batch files to end
}
```